# Javafx 8 lambda expression error

Tags: lambda, javafx-8

I got an illegal expression error when  compiling javafx program.
I have want to upload the screenshot but the stack exchange app. Is demanding that I need 10 reputation to be able to upload images!

```java
btn.setOnAction( e-> buttonClick() );
```

the compiler point the `e-->` as illegal expression

I install JDK 8 and have set my environment variable

Yet I still get the error...  guys help

Comment: What IDE are you using? Are you sure you are compiling with Java 8 and have set the compiler compliance level to 1.8?

Comment: I am using notepad++ .

Comment: Wow: I would strongly recommend using an IDE such as [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/home/index.php), [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) or [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). However, I assume you are compiling from the command line. What is the output if you type `javac -version`?

Comment: I saw javac 1.8.0_51

Comment: If, you are using notepad++ and CLI, Change the environment variable to jdk 8 path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out the fault 
The reason for the error is that jdk 7 was still install on my system!
I uninstall it and now it work

Answer (score 1):

If your are compiling using command line,You may be using jdk 7,try to set up JDK 8 from the environment variables.

Right click MyComputer->properties->Advanced System Settings Then in the advanced tab, select Environment variables, look for "path" under system variables look for your jdk path and change it to the jdk 8 path

in mycase [image: Image example]

If jdk 7 path also exists, don't forget to delete it